# Kendo UI Grid update event is not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have Kendo UI inline Grid. It read and populate the grid properly. but when i press edit and changes in any column and press update then update event is not firing.
and it also not calling controller method.

Hope someone can help me point out what I am doing wrong here.
following is my grid binding.

```
    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {

            read: function (options) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "./GetIngredients",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        options.success(result);
                    }
                });
            },

            update: function (options) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "./UpdateData",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                });
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                alert('1');
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    alert('2');
                    return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                }
            }
        },
        batch: true,
        pageSize: 20,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                fields: {
                    Id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    Division: { type: "string", editable: true, nullable: false },
                    GroupName: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
                    CategoryName: { type: "string" },
                    TypeName: { type: "string" },
                    ItemName: { type: "string" }
                }
            }
        }

    });

    var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid(
   {
       dataSource: dataSource,
       height: 430,
       scrollable: true,
       pageable: true,
       navigatable: true,
       columns: [
       { field: "Division", title: "Division", width: "80px" },
       { field: "GroupName", title: "Group Name", width: "70px" },
       { field: "CategoryName", title: "Category Name", width: "110px" },
       { field: "TypeName", title: "Type Name", width: "100px" },
       { field: "ItemName", width: "140px" },
       { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "170px" }],
       editable: "inline"
   }).data("kendoGrid");
```

following is the method in Homecontroller.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetIngredients()
    {
        IngredientData ingredientData = new IngredientData();
        ingredientData.Id = 1;
        ingredientData.DivisionId = 1;
        ingredientData.Division = "Division Abc";
        ingredientData.GroupId = 2;
        ingredientData.GroupName = "Group -A";
        ingredientData.CategoryId = 3;
        ingredientData.CategoryName = "Category -D";
        ingredientData.FoodTypeId = 4;
        ingredientData.TypeName = "Type One";
        ingredientData.ItemId = 5;
        ingredientData.ItemName = "Item One";

        return Json( ingredientData , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

 [HttpPost]
    public void UpdateData()
    {
        // logic for update data in database.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you realize that you have `batch` set to `true`? When in [`batch`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-batch) mode, you have to invoke `sync` on `dataSource` or [`saveChanges`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#methods-saveChanges) in Grid definition.

Try adding a toolbar command for invoking `saveChanges` as follow:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    height: 430,
    scrollable: true,
    pageable: true,
    navigatable: true,
    toolbar: [ "save" ],
    columns: [
        { field: "Division", title: "Division", width: "80px" },
        { field: "GroupName", title: "Group Name", width: "70px" },
        { field: "CategoryName", title: "Category Name", width: "110px" },
        { field: "TypeName", title: "Type Name", width: "100px" },
        { field: "ItemName", width: "140px" },
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "170px" }],
    editable: "inline"
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

or simply remove `batch` mode.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue.  But I have solved using this.

To fire create/delete/update we need to specify schema in dataSource( in schema we should mention atleast what is id field).

**schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "StudentID"
                }
            }**

Code:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
       transport: {
            read: function (options) {
                alert("read");              
            },
            create: function (options) {                    
                                   alert("create");             
            },
            update: function (options) {                    
                                   alert("update");                },
            destroy: function (options) {                    
                                   alert("destroy");                }
        },
                    schema: {
            model: {
                id: "StudentID"
            }
        }
```

Comment: you are right. solve my problem and save my life, thanks